# Iterate update statement with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops

`Tbl_campaign_details_direct` lists parameters per campaign (CampaignDuration is just a placeholder right now).

[image]

I want to link that table with `tbl_dim_date` (only an excerpt):

[image]

To do so, I want to write a TSQL statement that sets the column "CampaignDetailsDirectID" in `tbl_dim_date` automatically based on the date range (= "Campaign Start" and "Campaign Finish") defined in `tbl_campaign_details_direct`.

This means that for all DateIDs between 20150609 and 20150617 the column CampaignDetailsDirectID should get a "2" in `tbl_dim_date`. 
For all DateIDs between 20151126 and 20151201 a "1" in `tbl_dim_date`.

***For only one record*** in tbl_campaign_details_direct, my TSQL looks like this:

```
Declare @start int, @finish int, @CampaignID int
Set @start = (select cast(replace(CampaignStart,'-','')as int) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct])
Set @finish = (select cast(replace(CampaignFinish,'-','')as int) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct])

While @start <= @finish
Begin
    Update Reporting.dbo.dim_date
    Set CampaignDetailsDirectID = 1 --How to adjust to set respective CampaignDetailsDirectID automatically = campaign_details_direct.CampaignDetailsID?
    Where dim_date.DateID = @start
Set @start = @start + 1
End
Go -- How to iterate through all campaigns?
```

How do I have to adjust this query, so that it does not only apply to one campaign but iterates through all CampaignDetailsID in `tbl_campaign_details_direct`? Or is another approach to achieve the same result more useful?

New attempt which does not work as only the date range for Black Friday is updated. Anything obvious here?

```
Use [REPORTING] 
Go

Declare @start int, @finish int, @MAX_CampaignID int, @MIN_CampaignID int
Set @MAX_CampaignID = (select max(CampaignDetailsID) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct])
Set @MIN_CampaignID = (select min(CampaignDetailsID) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct])
Set @start = (select cast(replace(CampaignStart,'-','')as int) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct] where CampaignDetailsID = @MIN_CampaignID) 
Set @finish = (select cast(replace(CampaignFinish,'-','')as int) from [REPORTING].[dbo].[campaign_details_direct] where CampaignDetailsID = @MIN_CampaignID)

Select @start as start_date, @finish as end_date, @MAX_CampaignID as last_campaign_id, @MIN_CampaignID as first_campaign_id

While @MIN_CampaignID <= @MAX_CampaignID
Begin
    While @start <= @finish
        Begin
            Update Reporting.dbo.dim_date Set CampaignDetailsDirectID = @MIN_CampaignID
            Where dim_date.DateID = @start
                Set @start = @start + 1
        End
    Set @MIN_CampaignID = @MIN_CampaignID + 1
End
Go
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. A simple update that joins the tables will do what you want. But what do you expect to happen if you have overlapping date ranges??

Comment: How does that update statement look like? I can't seem to get it right... overlapping date ranges with campaigns have never happened so far... However, what would you recommend I do in case this occurs? How would you structure the tables?

Comment: This is my attempt now (s. edit above), but it seems as if the value of @Min_CampaignID is not changing as only the first date range for Black Friday is updated with a 1. Anything obvious??

Comment: Look up "tally table" and "numbers table". This technique is the standard way to replace an (inefficient) loop with an (efficient) single query in SQL. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/ and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Cool stuff! Honestly, I have no idea how to apply that to my problem.. Before resorting to this more efficient solution I would like to fix my (inefficient) loop construction as I can live with that inefficiency for now (rather small data set). Why is that loop not working?

Comment: How you want to handle overlapping dates is up to you. You have to decide which campaign id wins out since your date table can only hold one campaign id per date.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and that's why I was asking how you would design the table(s) to allow for multiple campaign ids per date in case that makes sense... Anyway, I just want to fix that loop and I have no idea how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is noone helping?